# Ignoring files - retrospectively adding files to .gitignore

Tags: git, version-control

I've noticed only recently that when I set up a new project, initialise git and add my .gitignore file, as long as I add the files I don't want version controlled prior to my initial git add / commit, all is fine - those files aren't tracked.

However, if I add a file retrospectively further down the line (one that has already been committed at some point, I'm finding git isn't ignoring these files at all - it's staging them as if they weren't in the .gitignore file at all.

Even when I commit my latest changes, then use `git rm -r --cached .`, then `git add .`, etc it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

My workaround at the moment is to use the following command:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged file.php
```

The problem with using the above is obviously remembering which files I've instructed git to assume are unchanged.

Has anyone else any issues with adding files that have previously been commited to .gitignore?

Comment: `.gitignore` is used to ignore certain files. But, once they're added to a repository, the file will always be tracked. Using `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is the way to go. Why do you need to know which files you have marked as `--assume-unchanged`? When you make a commit, if you want one of those files in the commit and it's not there, you'll just add it.

Comment: Very true, to reverse `--assume-unchanged` against a file, I've been using `--no-assume-unchanged`. It's been working for me fine, but have had a few occasions where I've forgotten to re-add a file for staging. Was curious to find out other people's experiences.

Comment: I haven't had the occasion to use `--assume-unchanged`, but I would bet that you don't have to change it to `--no-assume-unchanged` every time you want to add a file. Just add the file using `git add --force`

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a whirl to see how it works. Further to my other comment, I use `--assume-unchanged`, then `--no-assume-unchanged`, then refresh git's cache, then add / commit, etc. From what I understand, using `--force` can override the .gitignore file too, which can come in handy on rare occasions.

Comment: Exactly. Using `git add --force` overrides the `.gitignore` setting and, based on that, I'm guessing it would override the `--no-assume-unchanged` setting and save you from having to do the back and forth with `git update-index`